# how do I debug C in vs code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use VS code to debug my code but it threw an error message saying "the prelaunch task 'C/C++:gcc.exe build active file' terminate with exit code -1", I've followed the tutorial videos on youtube step by step to install all the extensions and pack but it just couldn't debug. Could someone help me out?

[image]

Comment: This looks like you try to compile `launch.json` instead of `grok.c`.